# How to avoid apparent contradiction in ZFC when constructing a infinitely nested chain of sets with a single element?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, set-theory, model-theory

Below is an attempt to describe a model $\mathcal{M}''$ of ZFC wherein a chain of sets $c_0 \ni c_1 \dots \ni c_p \ni \dots$ seemingly exists, even as a $\omega$-sequence $(c_0, c_1, \dots) \in \mathcal{M}''$ which if true would violate the axiom of regularity. More precisely, the construction is claimed (surely falsely) to yield sets $c_0 = \{c_1\}, c_1 = \{c_2\}, c_2 = \{c_3\}$, and so forth, and their sequence $(c_0, c_1, \dots)$ *inside* the model.

1. Begin with ZFC and its classical signature $\langle \varnothing, \varnothing, \{\in, =\}\rangle$. Assume ZFC is consistent. Then it has some model $\mathcal{M}$ via Henkin-Lindebaum arguments. We may fix the model $\mathcal{M}$ to be transitive, for if ZFC is consistent then also ZFC + “ZFC has transitive model” is consistent via a version of the reflection principle.
2. Add a countable infinity of constant symbols $c_0, c_1, c_2, \dots$ for a signature $\langle \{c_0, c_1, c_2, \dots\}, \varnothing, \{\in, =\}\rangle$. These constants will play the role of the infinite chain later on, cf. points 3 and 4. Note that the metainteger subindices are essentially placeholders and could be replaced by bars, i.e. $c, c_|, c_{||}$, et cetera.
3. Add a countable infinity of axioms $c_0 = \{c_1\}, c_1 = \{c_2\}, c_2 = \{c_3\}, \dots$. This can be accomplished via the axiom schema $\forall x (x \in c_i \Leftrightarrow x = c_{i+1})$ with $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. The bar interpretation has for $+1$ the appending of one additional bar. But perhaps the sets $c_p$ will start to repeat somewhere: for some $i \neq k$, it holds that $c_i = c_k$? We will avoid this with point 4.
4. Add a countable infinity of axioms $c_0 \neq c_1, c_0 \neq c_2, \dots, c_1 \neq c_2, c_1 \neq c_3, \dots$. The axioms claim that all sets $c_p$ are distinct, and this may be achieved via the axiom schema $c_i \neq c_j$ for $i\not\overset{\cdot}{=} j = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. (Equality with dot $\overset{\cdot}{=}$ means syntactic equality).

We will refer to the theory of ZFC plus points 2 to 4 by ZFC + C below.

Is this countably infinite addition of constants from 2, plus the axioms in 3 and 4 “fair game”? Meaning, that it will not lead to contradictions if ZFC is consistent? I claim the answer is *yes*; that no “additional” contradictions are possible in ZFC + C. This is the essence of points 5 to 9. The proof is by assumption to the contrary.

5. Assume to the contrary that ZFC + C is contradictory. In other words, that ZFC + C $\Vdash \mathcal{F} \wedge \neg\mathcal{F}$ for some (any) formula $\mathcal{F}$. Any proof of a contradiction $\mathcal{F} \wedge \neg\mathcal{F}$ will be finite, so too it must contain a finite number of new constants $c_{i_1}, c_{i_2}, \dots, c_{i_k}$ and a finite number of new axioms $\mathcal{A}_{j_1}, \mathcal{A}_{j_2}, \dots, \mathcal{A}_{j_m}$.
6. WLOG, since we may add new redundant branches and axioms to any proof, our proof of $\mathcal{F} \wedge \neg\mathcal{F}$ may be assumed to contain precisely new constants $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_k$ and new axioms $\mathcal{A}_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{2}, \dots, \mathcal{A}_{m}$ (after, possibly, a suitable renaming of $k$ and $m$). It will not matter much *for our purposes* how exactly the axioms are enumerated, so far as it is remembered that if an axiom $\mathcal{A}_j$ contains a constant symbol $c_i$, that $c_i$ will have been included amongst listed constants $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_k$.

Call the theory ZFC + $\{c_0, c_1, \dots, c_k\}$ + $\{\mathcal{A}_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{2}, \dots, \mathcal{A}_{m}\}$ by the name ZFC + D.

7. By definition of ZFC + D, it must also be the case that ZFC + D $\Vdash \mathcal{F} \wedge \neg\mathcal{F}$. In other words, ZFC + D must also be contradictory, should ZFC + C be contradictory. This will be in contradiction with point 8 where a model of ZFC + D is built. (In 9, we therefore conclude that our assumption in 5, of ZFC + C being contradictory, must be false).
8. ZFC + D *cannot* be contradictory because it has a model (if ZFC is not contradictory). Let us construct the model, which we will denote by $\mathcal{M}'$. We will turn the model $\mathcal{M}$ of ZFC into a model of ZFC + D. All to be done is to add an interpretation for constant symbols $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_k$. This may be done as follows:
   \begin{align*}
   c_k &:= \varnothing\\
   c_{k-1} &:= \{\varnothing\}\\
   c_{k-2} &:= \{\{\varnothing\}\}\\
   \vdots\\
   c_{1} &:= \underbrace{\{\dots\{}_{k-1 \text{ braces}} \hspace{-0.5em} \varnothing \hspace{-1.2em} \underbrace{\}\dots\}}_{\hspace{1.3em}k-1 \text{ braces}}\\
   c_{0} &:= \underbrace{\{\dots\{}_{k \text{ braces}} \hspace{-0.1em} \varnothing \hspace{-0.4em} \underbrace{\}\dots\}}_{\hspace{0.5em}k \text{ braces}}
   \end{align*}
   These sets are all pairwise different, thus satisfying any axioms of type 3 among $\mathcal{A}_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{2}, \dots, \mathcal{A}_{m}$. And $x \in c_i$ iff $x \in c_{i+1}$, meeting all axioms of type 2 among $\mathcal{A}_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{2}, \dots, \mathcal{A}_{m}$. Note that $\varnothing = \varnothing^\mathcal{M}$ because $\mathcal{M}$ is transitive.
9. On the one hand, we assumed that ZFC + C is contradictory which yielded a contradiction in ZFC + D. On the other hand, ZFC + D must be contradiction-free as it possesses a model, namely $\mathcal{M}'$. We conclude that ZFC + C must, in fact, be consistent provided ZFC is consistent. So additions in points 2 to 4 were “fair game”.
10. If ZFC + C is consistent, as it must be if ZFC is, then ZFC + C also has a model. Fix one such model $\mathcal{M}''$ which we may again assume to be transitive.

Finally, we attempt to argue that $\mathcal{M}''$ has contradictions.

11. It is derivable in ZF − Regularity that if regularity holds, then there is no $\omega$-sequence $f: \omega \to X$ of sets, $f := (X_0, X_1, \dots)$, such that $\forall i \in \omega\, (X_i \ni X_{i+1})$. Now $\mathcal{M}''$ is a model of ZFC + C, thus it has $c_0 \ni c_1 \dots \ni c_p \ni \dots$ (again, the indices of $c$'s are bars $|$). We conclude, again because $\mathcal{M}''$ is a model of ZFC + C, the sequence $(c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots) = (c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots)^{\mathcal{M}''}$ *cannot* exist inside $\mathcal{M}''$ to avoid contradictions. (The sequences are “the same” because $\mathcal{M}''$ is transitive, and being a function, $\omega$, $\mathrm{ran}$, $\mathrm{dom}$ are absolute wrt transitive models. As for the $c_p$'s, what will be most important about them in $\mathcal{M}''$ is captured by them satisfying axioms of type 2 and type 3).

In points 12 through 14 we will use transitive closure and recursion to show that $(c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots) \in \mathcal{M}''$ which is the crux of the issue.

12. Now, in ZF − Regularity one may prove, for any set $Y$, the existence of the transitive closure of $Y$, namely $\operatorname{TC}(Y)$. Here $\operatorname{TC}(Y)$ is the unique $\subseteq$-smallest transitive set such that $Y \in \operatorname{TC}(Y)$. One may prove that $\operatorname{TC}(Y) = \bigcup\{Y, \cup Y, \cup\cup Y, \dots\}$.
13. The transitive closure must thus also exist inside $\mathcal{M}''$ for any $Y \in \mathcal{M}''$. The transitive closure of a set is also absolute wrt transitive models, so, for $Y \in \mathcal{M}''$, $\operatorname{TC}(Y) = \operatorname{TC}(Y)^{\mathcal{M}''}$. Most notably, $\operatorname{TC}(c_0) \in \mathcal{M}''$, and since $\operatorname{TC}(c_0) = \{c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots\} =: \zeta$, then $\{c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots\} \in \mathcal{M}''$. (Taking a union is also absolute wrt transitive models).
14. Let us use recursion (provable in at least ZF) to construct the trouble-maker $(c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots)$ *inside* $\mathcal{M}''$. We proceed thusly.
    \begin{cases}
    u({0}_\omega) &= c_0,\\
    u({n^+}_\omega) &= F(u(n_\omega)) 
    \end{cases}
    where $F$ “picks the only element” inside of its argument set. More precisely, let $F = F(x, y)$ be the formula
    \begin{align*}F(x, y) \overset{\cdot}{=}&\ x \neq \varnothing \wedge \forall a \in x\, \forall b \in x\,(a = b) \wedge y \in x \vee\phantom{x}\\
    &\vee y = \varnothing.
    \end{align*}
    Therefore the recursion is justified. Furthermore, $u(n_\omega) = c_n$. Here $F(x, y)$ is (equivalent to) a $\Delta_0$-formula and ergo absolute wrt transitive models.
15. In conclusion, $u = (c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots)$ will exist inside $\mathcal{M}''$. This is in contradiction with the axiom of regularity which must also hold inside $M''$ as it is a model for ZFC (take $f := u$ for point 11).

---

- ***Q:*** What is a/the source of the problem here?

It is probably most comfortable to say, “Hey, the mistakes are in points numbered x, y, z”. This is part of the reason for introducing the numbering 1 to 15.

Comment: If you ever played with non-standard models of PA, you shouldn't be confused about non-standard models of ZF either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you have the time (admittedly, quite a bit of time due to the length of question), could you single out a point which contains a mistake? At first, I seemed fine with the construction because I thought that the sequence $(c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots)$ is outside the model. However, 12 to 15 *seem to* show that $(c_0, c_1, \dots, c_p, \dots)$ is in the model. I must admit to not have played extensively with non-standard models of PA.

Comment: Your mistake is hidden in the ellipses. In your model, the sequence $(c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots)$ continues past all the $c_n$ you have defined and settles to $\ldots, \varnothing, \varnothing, \varnothing, \ldots$.

Comment: The problem is with point (10).  Just because every finite part of $\mathsf{ZFC}+C$ has a transitive model, that doesn't mean $\mathsf{ZFC}+C$ has a transitive model (only that it has *a* model, and in such a model, the sequence $\langle c_i:i<\omega\rangle$ isn't in it). You can do all sorts of stuff with the compactness theorem (points (5) through (9)) but by and large the resulting models witnessing the weird theory is consistent will be weird.

Comment: @JunderscoreH Is that to say that the reflection principle fails in ZFC + C? Of course, it must still hold for formulae of ZFC but it must fail for some formula of the expanded language? Otherwise, one could still do ZFC consistent $\Rightarrow$ ZFC + C consistent $\Rightarrow$ ZFC + C +  “ZFC + C has transitive model”, right? Looking at the proof of the reflection principle, I assume the part that breaks down is in the “main lemma” of the reflection principle. It also means all models of ZFC + C must be non-transitive. I will think about it some more. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @LinearChristmas The error you're making doesn't have anything to do with ZFC vs ZFC + C. You must be misunderstanding the implications of the reflection theorem. It's not true by any means that Con(ZFC) implies Con(ZFC + "there is a transitive model of ZFC")... it's not even true that Con(ZFC + "there is a model of ZFC") implies Con(ZFC + "there is a transitive model of ZFC")

Comment: @LinearChristmas What makes you think the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+C$ has $C$ in it? The true $C$ really is stuck in some finite theory according to such a model.  So such a model's interpretation of the described infinite procedure will yield some other theory $C'$ that the model thinks can't have a transitive model of (recall that transitivity is defined relative to a background model).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen One argument may go as follows. Augment ZFC with a constant symbol, say $t$. Add an axiom saying that $t$ is transitive, and add all axioms of ZFC relativised to $t$. Now if ZFC + “there is a transitive model of ZFC” were inconsistent, there is a finite proof of a contradiction in it. In particular, it will use finitely many $t$-relativised ZFC axioms. Take that list, unrelativise it, use reflection principle on this list of formulae (name the set $T$). Take the proof of a contradiction in ZFC + $t$ + ... and replace $t$ in the proof with $T$ for a contradiction in ZFC.

Comment: @JunderscoreH Sorry, previous comment was meant for spaceisdarkgreen. Now replying to you. Are you asking about the set $\zeta$ as in OP when you say "has C in it"?

Comment: @LinearChristmas This theory you give a (correct) proof of the relative consistency of is not "ZFC + there is a transitive model of ZFC". In particular, it does not prove that t is a model of ZFC, it merely proves every ZFC axiom relativized to t.

Comment: @LinearChristmas No I'm referring to the theory $C$.  All of this comes back to the model misinterpretting $\omega$.  To define $C$, you need the sequence $\langle c_i:i<\omega\rangle$ which the model does not have: it only has initial segments and extensions of this.  There is a similar issue going on with your use of compactness to get a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$: if the model misinterprets $\omega$ it doesn't know what a formula truly is and so it misinterprets the schemes of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  In other words, $\mathsf{ZFC},C$ and the model's interpretation of $\mathsf{ZFC},C$ differ

Comment: @LinearChristmas: The point you are missing, it seems, is that when you use compactness argument, you are adding new natural numbers, and so new axioms. If $\varphi$ is a non-standard axiom in $\cal M$, then in what sense does $\cal M\models\varphi$ is a meaningful statement in the meta-theory? This ties back directly to the point about Reflection, which is a meta-theoretic theorem.

Comment: I will digest what all of you said and come back in a day or two, or sooner if possible. Thank you!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have let things simmer for a while. To my horror, it seems “$M$ is a transitive model of ZFC” does NOT mean “$M$ is a model of ZFC $\wedge$ $M$ is transitive”. Rather, it means “$M$ is a model of ZFC $\wedge$ $M$ is transitive $\wedge$ $M$ is standard” (whatever “standard” is supposed to be). Is that correct?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Please see previous comment. That said, unfortunately I am still not getting why $\mathrm{t}$ is not a transitive model of ZFC. Suppose again that we expand ZFC with the constant symbol $\mathrm{t}$, duplicate all axioms of ZFC with quantifiers bounded to $\mathrm{t}$. Finally, add the sentence $\forall x \forall y\, (y \in x \wedge x \in \mathrm{t} \Rightarrow y \in \mathrm{t})$ saying $\mathrm{t}$ is transitive. Call this theory ZFC$^+$. Does ZFC$^+$ prove that ZFC has a transitive model $\mathcal{M}$? I say take $\mathcal{M} := \mathrm{t}$. What is wrong here? (1/2)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen (2/2) Justification for picking $\mathcal{M} := \mathrm{t}$: (1) all axioms of ZFC hold inside $\mathrm{t}$; (2) $\mathrm{t}$ is transitive; (3) $\mathrm{t}$ is standard. Maybe I should ask a new question along these lines? It would be perhaps be easier than continuing the discussion here + potentially more useful for others with similar troubles in future.

Comment: I will also say that I am probably thinking of models in a "purely" meta-theoretic sense. More precicely, I have not considered "coding arithmetically" the notion "model" etc. Maybe that is also where my understanding lacks... But I do not see why an "arithmetic coding" would be necessary, or why set theory should have to respect the coding that I choose.

Comment: @LinearChristmas Not every model of ZFC+ satisfies “t is a model of ZFC”. In a given model, the set $t$ is interpreted as satisfies all standard axioms by assumption but what about the nonstandard ones?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You say that "In a given model [of ZFC+], the set $\mathrm{t}$ is interpreted as satisf[ying] all standard axioms by assumption". I agree with this part :). You imply that "there may also be non-standard axioms that $\mathrm{t}$" satisfies in that model. I suppose that is also fair. But why would this break the fact that $\mathrm{t}$ is a model of ZFC? Or did you mean to say in the first sentence of your latest comment that  not every model of ZFC+ satisfies "t is a *transitive* model"?

Comment: @LinearChristmas well clearly every model satisfies “$t$ is transitive”… that is an axiom of ZFC+. A model of ZFC+ thinks $t$ is transitive, but not necessarily a model of ZFC, and that’s what’s important in ascertaining whether ZFC+ proves $t$ is a transitive model of ZFC or not. Who cares what it “is”? or are you making the unwarranted assumption that the model of ZFC+ is transitive and concluding what it “is” is a transitive model of ZFC?

Comment: @LinearChristmas (And I think this was a typo in your last comment but in case it isn’t, I’m saying that according to the model, there may be nonstandard ZFC axioms that $t$ *doesn’t* satisfy.)

Comment: @LinearChristmas I tried to encapsulate this in an answer. Regarding “standard”, “standard”  usually means the model’s membership relation is $\in$, i.e. the membership relation of the metatheory. Just saying the domain of the model is a transitive set means nothing if you don’t make any requirements on the model’s membership relation… you could always just replace the domain with some non transitive set with the same cardinality and adjust the membership relation so it is isomorphic to the original model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134273/discussion-between-linear-christmas-and-spaceisdarkgreen). (Ping me there if you are up for a chat in Chat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compactness argument that there is a model of what you're calling $\sf ZFC +C$ (assuming there is a model of $\sf ZFC$) is fine, but the issue is when you extrapolate that to saying $\sf ZFC + C$ has a transitive model. Everything after that is moot because it plainly doesn't, at least provided we're assuming foundation in the metatheory. A model of $\sf ZFC + C$ is necessarily not-well-founded and thus not transitive... that's sort of the point of the construction. It's as if you've shown the existence of a nonstandard model of arithmetic with compactness, and then you turn around and say "we can assume the model is $\mathbb N$".

The existence of a model of some theory doesn't usually imply the existence of a well-founded/transitive model of that theory, even in the case where there are no obvious problems. For instance, if there were a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$, then the minimal tranistive model (i.e. $L_\alpha$ for the minimal $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha \models \sf ZFC$) thinks there are no transitive models, but it is arithmetically sound so it knows that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent. Thus it is consistent that there are no transitive models of $\sf ZFC,$ even in the case that there are models of $\sf ZFC.$

You attempt to rebut this in the comments by giving an argument that $\sf Con(ZFC)\to Con(ZFC^+)$ where $\sf ZFC^+$ is a theory in an expanded language with a constant symbol $t$ whose axioms are $\sf ZFC$ $\cup$ {"$t$ is transitive"} $\cup$ $\{\varphi^t: t\in \sf ZFC\}.$ This proof is correct, but the consistency of $\sf ZFC^+$ doesn't imply the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ + "there is a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$." Sure, you get a model of $\sf ZFC^+$, but this model may have nonstandard integers, and hence nonstandard axioms in its internal version of $\sf ZFC$. The $t$-relativized axioms (and the theorem schema $\varphi^t\leftrightarrow t\models \ulcorner \varphi \urcorner$) only allow you to conclude that $M\models (t\models \ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ for the standard (i.e. actual) axioms $\varphi$ of $\sf ZFC$ and it may be that $M$ thinks that $t$ fails to satisfy some (nonstandard) axioms. So you aren't guaranteed that $M\models (t\models \ulcorner \sf ZFC\urcorner)$ any more than you would be guaranteed that some model $M$ of $\sf PA$ has $M\models \forall x\varphi(x)$ just on the basis that for all $n\in\mathbb N,$ $M\models\varphi(S^n0).$

Now, if you were guaranteed a *transitive* model of $\sf ZFC^+,$ or even just a model with standard integers, things would be different, but the whole point of this discussion is that you aren't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think it would be ideal (for me, that is) for us to share a short chat session. Until that time, I will ask here in the comments. I will focus on exactly one point at a time for maximum clarity. ||||||||

Comment: Q: What is a “metatheory” to you here? Is it (1) a non-formalised logic system with finitistic arumentation, including structural induction on first-order formulae? Or does it (2) also include a sense of “the intended interpretation of ZFC”? Or are you (3) talking about some formalised metatheory such as PA? Or (4) something else? When I think of metatheory,  I think of it as mostly being (1). There are some basic things that may be done with meta sets, but I am not sure that I do accept that sets in the metatheory in the sense of (1) must be well-founded.

Comment: I still need serious practice with metatheoretic considerations, and need to learn about the coding ideas. Especially since I still very-very much wish to write $\textsf{ZFC}^+ \Vdash t\models \ulcorner \sf ZFC \urcorner$ which is *not* true (some models of $\sf{ZFC}^+$ think there are non-standard $\sf{ZFC}$ axioms). It's probably because I have thought about $\textsf{ZFC}^+ \Vdash t\models \ulcorner \sf ZFC \urcorner$ as meaning $\textsf{ZFC}^+ \Vdash \varphi^t$ for all (standard) axioms of ZFC. In the meantime, your answer deserves to be accepted. Thank you for all your help (thus far)!

Comment: I have asked a question which was touched upon in our chat: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4473090/300912. In a hopefully more succinct form. Feel free to chime in, or not to chime in.