# Are there dangers to relativising a formula in ZFC twice wrt to an added constant symbol $\mathrm{M}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Begin with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in signature $\langle \{\mathrm{M}\}, \varnothing, \{\in, =\} \rangle$ where $\mathrm{M}$ is a constant symbol. Define the relativisation $\varphi^{C,\in} =: \varphi^C$ for any formula $\varphi$ and class $C$ in the usual way. Finally, for any axiom $\phi$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ add the an axiom $\phi^\mathrm{M}$ to the theory, plus the requirement that $\mathrm{M}$ be $\in$-transitive. Call the resulting system $\mathsf{ZFC+}$.

Fix any formula $\varphi$ in $\mathsf{ZFC+}.$ One may consider its relativisation to any class, say $C$, and repeat the process, ad infinitum, relativising $\varphi^C$ to $C$, giving $(\varphi^C)^C$, and so on. In particular, one may consider relativising $\varphi$ to $\mathrm{M}$ multiple times, for example $\varphi^\mathrm{M}$, $(\varphi^\mathrm{M})^\mathrm{M}$, $((\varphi^\mathrm{M})^\mathrm{M})^\mathrm{M}$.

- What would be the result of relativising $\varphi$ to $\mathrm{M}$ multiple times? Is there a danger in doing so, *in the sense* that some common result for relativisation will cease to hold?

My intuition tells me that that this iteration is fine, and that $\varphi^\mathrm{M}$ is a “fixed point” of repeated relativisation to $\mathrm{M}$, in that $\varphi^\mathrm{M} \Leftrightarrow \varphi^{\mathrm{M}^{(n)}}$ for any $n = 1, 2, 3, \dotsc$. I offer regardless arguments for both sides:

1. *Why it would make sense?* It  would be similar to the situation where $C := \mathrm{V}$, where $\mathrm{V}$ is the universe of all sets (that is, $x = x$). Then $\varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi^\mathrm{V} \Leftrightarrow (\varphi^\mathrm{V})^\mathrm{V} \Leftrightarrow \cdots$. For $C := \mathrm{M}$, the analog of $\varphi$ for $\mathrm{V}$ is $\varphi^\mathrm{M}$, so the sequence is “shifted once over” but otherwise the argument is the same, with $x \in \mathrm{M}$ instead of $x = x$ as definition of $C$.
2. *Why would it* not *make sense?* One has the vague notion that relativisation should, in a way, mimic an interpretation. So relativising to $\mathrm{M}$ would be akin to interpreting the formula in $\mathrm{M}$. However, constant symbols are classically interpreted as elements of the set; if $\mathrm{M}$ is already in the formula, then $\mathrm{M}$ should be interpreted to be an element of $\mathrm{M}$. This makes $\mathrm{M}^\mathrm{M} = \mathrm{M}$ impossible via $\mathrm{M} \notin \mathrm{M}$. From this point of view, while syntactically possible to iterate the relativisation, it loses the connection to interpretations. Therefore, one might be concerned, morally, that some useful result of relativisations will cease to hold.

---

There is no immediate application I have in mind, such that relativising a formula twice wrt to $\mathrm{M}$ is essential. It could be used, *non-essentially*, in some cases. To prove that the result of a recursion with elements of $\mathrm{M}$ done in $\mathrm{V}$ yields only elements inside $\mathrm{M}$ for the sake of an example. Nevertheless, the principal aim of this question is to improve my understanding, and that of others should they face a similar conundrum.

Comment: What you're considering is not even syntactically possible. For any formula $\varphi$ *in the language of set theory*, you can relativize to $M$, obtaining a formula $\varphi^M$. But now $\varphi^M$ is a formula in the augmented language with $M$ as a constant symbol. How do you relativize formulas in the augmented language to $M$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I start here with $\mathrm{M}$ present in the signature, I admit the "as usual" was not clear. Here is the gist: when relativising to $\mathrm{M}$, one would leave atomic formulae (with or without $\mathrm{M}$) untouched, then proceeding via recursion in the usual way. Meaning, ultimately, that quantifiers are restricted to $\mathrm{M}$, possibly for a second time if they were already restricted so; rest does not change. A partial rewording of the question: Will such a definition have similar properties to usual relativisation? Hopefully this helps. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: With this definition of relativization, even relativizing once doesn't do what you want! The key property of relativization to $M$ is that for any sentence $\varphi$ in the language of set theory, we have $V\models \varphi^M$ and only if $M\models \varphi$. When $\varphi$ is a sentence in the augmented language with the extra constant symbol, it makes no sense to ask whether $M\models \varphi$, since $M$ does not have an interpretation of the constant symbol $M$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm chiefly following exposition in Weaver's *Forcing for mathematicians*. There's a chapter on relativisation, chapter 6. In §3: "The notion of relativization is accompanied by a range of terminology. Instead of asserting [$\phi^M$] we may...[e]quivalently assert that...$M$ models $\phi$, which is symbolically written as $M \models \phi$. [I]t is important to understand that...for our purposes these other expressions...are all nothing more than synonyms of [$\phi^M$]". (1/2)

Comment: @AlexKruckman From this perspective, $V \models \phi^M \Leftrightarrow M \models \phi$ seems a given simply by definition. Because they both mean derivability of $\phi^M$. (2/2)

Comment: In Weaver's text, $\phi$ is supposed to be a formula in the language of set theory. Now if you want to, you can define a relativization $\phi^M$ for other formulas, and you can define "$M\models \phi$" to mean "$\phi^M$ is derivable". But if you do this, $M\models \phi$ will have *nothing to do* with the usual model-theoretic meaning of $M\models \phi$, which seems bad. Because, to repeat myself, $M\models \phi$ *makes no sense* when $\phi$ contains the constant symbol $M$.

Comment: Maybe an example of what can go wrong would help. Let $M$ be a model of ZFC. Consider the formula $\forall x\, (x\in M)$. Its "relativization to $M$" (by your definition) is $\forall x\in M\, (x\in M)$, which is shorthand for $\forall x\, (x\in M\to x\in M)$. Now this sentence is valid, so we conclude (by your definition) that $M\models \forall x\, (x\in M)$. Since $M$ is a term, we should be able to conclude that $M\models \exists y\, \forall x\, (x\in y)$, i.e., $M$ has a universal set. Which it doesn't, since it is a model of ZFC. This is problematic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for the example. One aspect I find to be confusing: the step of introducing an existential quantifier. If we go by my definition, then $\mathrm{M} \models \forall x \, (x \in \mathrm{M})$ means the same as ZFC being able to derive $\forall x \, (x \in \mathrm{M} \Rightarrow x \in \mathrm{M})$, as you observed. Introducing an existential quantifier to replace the term $\mathrm{M}$ would yield $\exists y\, \forall x\, (x\in y \Rightarrow x \in y)$ which is a valid tautology in a non-empty universe. (1/2)

Comment: @AlexKruckman In particular, $\mathrm{M} \models \exists y\, \forall x\, (x\in y \Rightarrow x \in y)$ will hold. This is different from your end result $\mathrm{M} \models \exists y\, \forall x\, (x \in y)$ which indeed cannot hold. May I ask you to clarify why you say *[W]e should be able to conclude that* $\mathrm{M} \models \exists y\, \forall x\, (x \in y)$? (2/2)

Comment: If $M$ is a structure and $t$ is a term, and $M\models \varphi(t)$, then $M\models \exists y\,\varphi(y)$. This is a basic rule of logic, and it breaks down in the example above, when we take $t$ to be $M$ and $\varphi$ to be $\forall x\, x\in y$. Now the reason it breaks down is that $\models$ is not the usual satisfaction relation - it's shorthand for ZFC derivability of your definition of the relativization. But my point is that if your definitions and notational conventions produce results that clash badly with the usual usage of the terminology and notation, then they're not good choices.

Comment: (1/2) Thank you for your response. I agree with your sentiment, and I think I should learn about arithmetisation of metamathematics which I have yet not done. Of course, since relativisation for normal ZFC formulae remains unchanged, this problem can only turn up with formulae containing $\mathrm{M}$. In mathematics, one often generalises certain things at the cost of losing one or another property; the question then becomes whether the generalisation is worth giving up some nice property.

Comment: (2/2) @AlexKruckman In this case, with the generalised definition one could relativise long formulae whose short subformula has $\mathrm{M}$ in it and the remaining formula does not have $\mathrm{M}$ anywhere. With the usual definition, I could not formally relativise the formula wrt $\mathrm{M}$ since it has $\mathrm{M}$ in it. With the new definition, some arguments might thus be shorter... I'll think about it at a later date. Until then, I think your comments do answer the question in OP. If you wish to at some time to convert it into an answer (or do so at a later date), I would accept.